# Removing NULLs in sequential data - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sql-view, locf

I have a database for tracking claims payments. There's a table for claims `claim`, a table for monthly payments `claim_month` and a table defining each month `month`. `month` has each entry in order so that if `month_id[1] > month_id[2]` then the second figure is earlier than the first figure.

Using the query (the randomisation of `paid_to_date` is added for privacy purposes):

```
SELECT
claim.claim_id,
m.month_id,
claim_month_id,
IF (claim_month.paid_to_date IS NOT NULL, ROUND(RAND(1) * 100), NULL) AS paid_to_date
FROM
    claim
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT month_id FROM claim_month ) AS m
    LEFT JOIN claim_month ON claim.claim_id = claim_month.claim_id 
    AND m.month_id = claim_month.month_id
```

I get the following data.

```
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (25, 1004, 8584, 41);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (25, 1005, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (25, 1006, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (25, 1007, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (21, 1004, 8580, 87);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (21, 1005, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (21, 1006, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (21, 1007, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (5, 1004, 8564, 14);
INSERT INTO ``(`claim_id`, `month_id`, `claim_month_id`, `paid_to_date`) VALUES (5, 1005, 8627, 9);
```

[image: Data visualised]

From here, I need to replace NULLs with the latest non-null observation for each `claim_id`.

- Since I'm using MariaDB/MYSQL, the LAG function doesn't allow for ignoring NULLs which is unfortunate since it appears to be perfect.
- I've also looked into using COALESCE and partitioning it, but that doesn't seem to be allowed either.
- I've also looked into using user defined functions however I'm using multiple data types and can't seem to work out how to define a function that doesn't require setting the output data type.

I've spent the whole morning looking through previous questions however most of them are for PostgresSQL which isn't particularly helpful in this context. What am I missing?

Comment: Please also post sample data for `claim_month` table.

Comment: claim_month is essentially the same as the view here, except without any rows with NULLs

Comment: No pictures thanks. Formatted text works just fine (along with a desired result, similarly formatted)

Comment: Surely it can't hurt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out a solution, but I'm not convinced it's the best. I suspect that for larger databases, this would be quite demanding. It works in the meantime however.

I've essentially joined the table onto itself repeatedly wherever a record is earlier and on the same claim using something similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    b.claim_id,
    b.month_id,
    b.claim_month_id,
    claim_month.claim_month_id AS claim_month_id_latest

FROM

(SELECT
    a.claim_id,
    a.month_id,
    a.claim_month_id,
    MAX(claim_month.month_id) AS source_month_id

FROM
    (
    SELECT
        claim.claim_id,
        m.month_id,
        claim_month_id
    FROM
        claim
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT month_id FROM claim_month ) AS m
        LEFT JOIN claim_month ON claim.claim_id = claim_month.claim_id 
        AND m.month_id = claim_month.month_id 

    ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN claim_month ON a.claim_id = claim_month.claim_id 
                                                AND a.month_id >= claim_month.month_id

GROUP BY
    a.claim_id, a.month_id) AS b
    LEFT JOIN claim_month ON b.claim_id = claim_month.claim_id AND b.source_month_id = claim_month.month_id


ORDER BY b.claim_id, b.month_id
```